# Altiris gets Disabled?

Tags: windows-xp, configuration-management

We use Altiris for software deployment at our organization. Sometimes when we remove a piece of software altiris will turn gray and every feature is disabled in it. The only way to fix that is to reinstall it. Does anyone know why it happens and what is the best way to fix it other than reinstallation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're saying when you remove a critical part of Altiris, then Altiris stops working until you reinstall that part? I'd say the solution is to not uninstall that part in the first place. Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Sorry, what I am saying is that if I remove a piece of software that Altiris has installed like Office 2007 or Adobe Acrobat, thats when Altiris stops working. I am just using it the way it was intended to.

Answer (score 1):

Altiris usually turns a item grey and disables all of the advertised tasks after a given task is complete.  So in this case when you assigned the Office 2007 software package to a system, that advertised task remains active until the task is complete.  Most tasks are complete and are disabled after completing the task, however an exception to this may be a task which runs repeatedly (i.e. any of the inventory tasks). So your problem is that the task is running on the system and then mark it as complete....time passes you remove an application from that system, however Altiris is setup to rescan a system to see if that task needs to be re-ran.  If you want this to occur you'll have to create a new advertised task or remove the history on that system which shows that the given task has already been ran on it (this is essentially what removing the AexAgent does).  To remove it from the history on the local system you must modify the .xml file on the client which reports this information (sorry I'm not sure exactly which .xml file, but it's in the same `%programfiles%\Altiris\Altiris Agent` folder.

Please note removing the computer from the collection...and then re-adding it will not suffice because the hstory of that task being ran on that system still exists.